# Is one Short Tandem Repeat (STR) enough for a reliable identification?

Tags: molecular-biology

The lab simulates the analysis of just one STR in the genome. Would this analysis be sufficient for a reliable identification in real life? If not, explain what could be done using DNA to identify someone more reliably.

Comment: From the phraseology this is almost certainly a homework question. The poster is presumably long gone, but the appropriate  course of action would seem to declare it off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

One STR is certainly not enough for identification because the same STR could be shared by many individuals. Combinations of many STRs, however, would be sufficient for identification. The number needed would depend on how many variants of the STR exist in the population (or species, depending on what you are identifying), and what the mutation rate is (nuclear STRs mutate relatively rapidly compared to some other genetic markers, but they are still often used because they're cheap and easy to genotype).